# How to supress zoom out behaviour from Essbase while retrieving data?

Tags: vb.net, essbase

I have written some code to extract data from Essbase. Before retrieving the data I Zoom In on one of the cell and then run the code to retrieve data. However, after successfully retrieving the data it zoom out to show only top generation. How can I avoid Zoom out after retrieve?

```
    x = Essbase.EssVConnect(DirectCast("[" & Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name & "]" &   Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet.Name, String), "user", "password", "server", "application", "database")

    Dim range As Excel.Range = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Range("ESSQRY_AT1")
    x = Essbase.EssVRetrieve(DirectCast("[" & Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name & "]" & Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet.Name, String), range, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide more code to see what's going on (e.g., the code before and after the statements you posted). Essbase retrieves data into a new grid object -- is it possible that you are looking at the original grid and that's why it appears to have been zoomed out?